# When I run this code in C++ on Windows in Visual Studio Code, it malfunctions

Tags: c++

I want this code to print "On the table" if I write "Laptop" or
"laptop", but when I write something else other than that, it prints "On the table". Here's the code... (C++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string object;

    cout << "Hi, I am you stuff assistant. How can I help you? \n";
    cin >> object;

    if (object == "Laptop", "laptop") {

        cout << "\nOn the table";
    }
    else {

        cout << "Unknown";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(object == "Laptop", "laptop"){` This is not how you compare multiple values. Use logical OR: `if (object == "Laptop" || object == "laptop") {`

Comment: Another option is to convert the string to all lower case and just do one comparison.

Answer (score 4):

The condition `object == "Laptop", "laptop"` means `"laptop"`. `"laptop"` is an array of characters and it will be converted to a pointer to the first element of that. It won't be `nullptr`, so it will always be true.

The `,` used here is a *comma operator*. It

1. Evaluate the lefthand operand and discard the result
2. Evaluate the righthand operand and return the result

Instead of that, you should compare with each strings.

Also you should add `#include <string>` to use `std::string` and remove `#include` of headers that are not used, especially non-standard ones.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string object;


    cout<<"Hi, I am you stuff assistant. How can I help you? \n";
    cin>>object;

    if(object == "Laptop" || object == "laptop"){

        cout<<"\nOn the table";

    } else {

        cout<<"Unknown";

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is here:

```
if(object == "Laptop", "laptop"){
    cout<<"\nOn the table";
}
```

Here you will get result of `,` operator, so this statement will always be true.